# Relay: How to avoid repeated DB queries while taking advantage of nodeDefinitions

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

My question is regarding requiring the user upon pagination. Taking the relay starter kit as a base example,

```
class User {}
class Widget {}

// Mock data
var viewer = new User();
viewer.id = '1';  

getUser: (id) => id === viewer.id ? viewer : null,
getViewer: () => viewer,
```

if this was a real db,  `viewer` would be a request to the database. Let's call this `fetchUser(id)`.

Every time we make the request from the `nodeDefinitions` on 'User', we call `getUser()` which makes the request to the db for `fetchUser(id)`.

```
var {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    var {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);
    if (type === 'User') {
      return getUser(id);
```

When we paginate through a fragment on 'User' example through a long infinite scroll of widgets by calling widgets(first: $count), for example, by incrementing `$count` by 3, then we are repeatedly making the request `fetchUser(id)` to the database for each pagination. This is blocking the data pagination by making a request each time for the same piece of data.

I'm aware of data loader , but is there a simpler way to cache this request, rather than having to make a db query ?

```
var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  description: 'A person who uses our app',
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField('User'),
    widgets: {
      type: widgetConnection,
      description: 'A person\'s collection of widgets',
      args: connectionArgs,
      resolve: (_, args) => connectionFromArray(getWidgets(), args),
    },
  }),
```